# Redirect a category and all it's post to a new URL with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redirect all urls of a category to new domain.

For Example, test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/how-to-lockunlock-a-user-2 to joomla5.guru99.com/how-to-lockunlock-a-user-2.html. 
I want to do this for all such urls

And,

want to redirect test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials to 
joomla5.guru99.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials.html.

I have wrote following directives in .htaccess

```
Redirect 301 /sap-basis-training-tutorials/ http://joomla5.guru99.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials.html
Redirect 301 /sap-basis-training-tutorials/how-to-lockunlock-a-user-2 http://joomla5.guru99.com/how-to-lockunlock-a-user-2.html
```

First one redirects fine but in later one, showing page not found error. It's actually redirecting but not at correct url and found following url in browser's address bar.

'http://joomla5.guru99.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials.htmlhow-to-lockunlock-a-user-2'

How can i solve this issue, Please assist me in right direction and help me to solve this.

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `RedirectMatch` instead of `Redirect` for regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/sap-basis-training-tutorials/(.+?)/?$ http://joomla5.guru99.com/$1.html

RedirectMatch 301 ^/(sap-basis-training-tutorials)/?$ http://joomla5.guru99.com/$1.html
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I have put your code in my .htaccess file but it's not working, same problem occurs. Apache restart required??

Comment: Change in .htaccess doesn't require restart. Make sure these 2 lines are right at the top and you test in a new browser.

Comment: Still, it's not working. Here is my htaccess sheet's snapshot-http://screencast.com/t/BWbGyz8sP Now I have tried http://test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/sap-basis-interview-questions, It should redirect to http://joomla5.guru99.com/sap-basis-interview-questions.html but it's not getting redirected.

Comment: No you didn't follow my instruction. I wrote ***Make sure these 2 lines are right at the top** Move these 301 rules above `# BEGIN Wordpress` line.

Comment: I have also moved this line before # BEGIN wordpress line but still no progress. Here's snapshot of htaccess- http://screencast.com/t/18j1YEvkY

Comment: I just retested rule is working fine. Even on your site it works fine. Try this link `http://test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/`

Comment: Looks like you are trying a different URL. I have updated my rule, try that now.

Comment: Yes working but a problem occurs. Now for http://test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/, it's redirecting to http://joomla5.guru99.com/.html and showing 403 forbidden error, how i can tackle this??

Comment: Where should `http://test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/` be redirected to?

Comment: http://test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/ to http://joomla5.guru99.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials.html
And if there is any url like  
http://test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/xyz/
then it should redirect to
http://joomla5.guru99.com/xyz.html
And I have many urls having this scenario

Comment: Yes both are working fine,but if I enter forward slash (/) at end of url it's showing 404 error. Like,test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/ or  test.saptraininghub.com/sap-basis-training-tutorials/xyz/ so how I can suppress / so that url gets redirected correctly with or without / at end